# Why is webpack's event listener hook called `plugin` and not something like `on`?

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

When creating a [webpack plugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/plugins), the way one listens to lifecycle events is by calling `compiler.plugin`, like this example, which calls the callback function when the `compile` event is emitted;

```
MyPlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
  compiler.plugin("compile", function(params) {
    console.log("The compiler is starting to compile...");
  });
```

My question is, why did the Webpack team choose this peculiar naming scheme? As they seem to be using the [Event Pattern (aka Observer Pattern)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), **wouldn't it have been much more appropriate to call the function "`on`", for instance**:

```
MyPlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
  compiler.on("compile", function(params) {
    console.log("The compiler is starting to compile...");
  });
```

Comment: this is more of a question to be wrote on their repository than wrote here, ask directly on their issues, nobody that actually knows the answer usually comes here

Comment: My thinking/hope is that someone with a lot of experience in Webpack will know the reason based on some facts that a beginner like me is not aware of

Comment: The "new" .plugin architecture is sort of new, it came with the new 4.0 release. Give it a try opening an issue there, maybe yourself could answer this question and contribute with everyone